# motion 4.1.1 - snapshot

Tags: motion

I use motion 4.1.1 for my camera.

The motion detection works fine and every hour I take a snapshot with following command through the webif.

`curl http://localhost:8080/0/action/snapshot`

Is it possible that these snapshots will be taken with other parametes (x,y resolution and quality) than for normal snapshots made by the motion detection?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- I'm not sure and didn't test it yet, although, make the resolution larger on the frame section of the config file. It improves the stream quality and may affect the snapshots, too.